# Find an element by ID is unreliable, but how reliable it is to find an element by Xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have been writing automated test cases for my company using Selenium in Python.

My test cases fail almost every day as for a given element, it has a different ID on different servers. I did some research this morning, its Xpath seems to be relatively consistent.

For example:

- An element was named "panel-xxxx_header_hd", this "xxxx" is a four-digit string; for a given element, it can be 1028, 1029 or 1030.

May I ask for you opinions on this? I know it is hard to prove statistically which one is more reliable.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the HTML, and give some examples of how the ID varies.

Comment: It's as stable as the DOM is.

Comment: Thank you Richard, thank you roippi.

Comment: seems like its worth a shot. You can use [regular expressions in xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#string.match), something like `"panel-...._header_hd"` and see how it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, those are XPath 2.0, which isn't supported by any major browser.

Comment: @Richard - rats. I've used regex in xpath... must have been an extension on the xpath engine. I'm not sure how selenium does its thing, but worth some exploring.

Comment: There are other identifiers as well like classname, tagname try those as well.
Well using a dynamic identifier is not a good option any day, this should be kept in mind while creating scripts.

Comment: This question still lacks information. Post actual HTML, show the "relatively consistent XPath expressions". How do you expect anyone to have an opinion on something that is "relatively consistent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Contains() to look for a partial ID.

Assuming there aren't any other elements that contain "_header_hd" in their ID you could use the following xpath (change the * to whatever kind of element you're expecting):

```
//*[contains(@id, '_header_hd')]
```

Or if you want to get a little more specific you could use a [CSS selector](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors) to find the element with an ID that *ends* with that substring (again, change the * to the type of element you're expecting:

```
*[id$='_header_hd']
```